# RPC Connection Filtered with no Firewalls

Tags: windows-7, firewall, tcp, windows-domain, rpc

I have a workstation (`PC1`) that cannot communicate with a domain controller over RPC (TCP/135).

```
C:\PortQryV2> portqry.exe -n 192.168.1.1 -p tcp -o 135

Querying target system called:

 192.168.1.1

Attempting to resolve IP address to a name...

IP address resolved to dc.domain.local

querying...

TCP port 135 <epmap service>: FILTERED
```

Executing the same command on another workstation (`PC2`) in the same subnet and VLAN shows `LISTENING` along with all of the server's RPC endpoints.

```
C:\>netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp

Protocol tcp Dynamic Port Range
---------------------------------
Start Port      : 49152
Number of Ports : 16384
```

The dynamic port range is the same on both `PC1` and `PC2`.

Both `PC1` and `PC2` are running Windows 7 Enterprise SP1.

McAfee Host Intrusion Prevention (HIPS) software used to be installed on `PC1` but was removed during the troubleshooting process.  It remains installed on `PC2`.  Both `PC1` and `PC2` used the same HIPS policy.

Windows firewall is currently disabled on `PC1`.

```
C:\>netsh advfirewall show allprofiles

Domain Profile Settings:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 OFF
Firewall Policy                       AllowInbound,AllowOutbound
LocalFirewallRules                    N/A (GPO-store only)
LocalConSecRules                      N/A (GPO-store only)
InboundUserNotification               Enable
RemoteManagement                      Disable
UnicastResponseToMulticast            Enable

Logging:
LogAllowedConnections                 Disable
LogDroppedConnections                 Disable
FileName                              %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
MaxFileSize                           4096


Private Profile Settings:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 OFF
Firewall Policy                       AllowInbound,AllowOutbound
LocalFirewallRules                    N/A (GPO-store only)
LocalConSecRules                      N/A (GPO-store only)
InboundUserNotification               Enable
RemoteManagement                      Disable
UnicastResponseToMulticast            Enable

Logging:
LogAllowedConnections                 Disable
LogDroppedConnections                 Disable
FileName                              %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
MaxFileSize                           4096


Public Profile Settings:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 OFF
Firewall Policy                       AllowInbound,AllowOutbound
LocalFirewallRules                    N/A (GPO-store only)
LocalConSecRules                      N/A (GPO-store only)
InboundUserNotification               Enable
RemoteManagement                      Disable
UnicastResponseToMulticast            Enable

Logging:
LogAllowedConnections                 Disable
LogDroppedConnections                 Disable
FileName                              %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
MaxFileSize                           4096

Ok.
```

I captured the RPC connection from `portqry.exe` using Wireshark and found that the `TCP SYN` DPU was sent, but no `ACK` ever received.  The TCP SYN was sent twice more, displaying in Wireshark as `[TCP Retransmission]`.  Later, I captured the same RPC communication on the domain controller using Wireshark.  I saw the incoming `TCP SYN` but saw no `SYN ACK` reply.  It's as though the domain controller is arbitrarily ignoring just this computer on just this port.  Note that querying Kerberos (UDP/88) works just fine from `PC1`.

I also tried rebuilding the TCP/IP stack on `PC1`, to no avail.

Any ideas on what could be preventing this communication?

Comment: Wireshark on the other machine sees the connection inbound?

Comment: I can't install Winpcap on the domain controller since we're in a protected environment.  It would take a while to get necessary approvals.

Comment: can you telnet to the port?  Does it connect?

Comment: `telnet 192.168.1.1 135` fails on `PC1` but succeeds on `PC2`.

Comment: You've got some blocking going on there then.  PC1 is your issue.  Can you create a firewall rule on it to allow inbound from PC2 port 135?

Comment: Windows firewall is disabled. However, I did try to enable it and created a rule to allow TCP/135 out, to no avail.  I also tried restoring Windows Firewall to defaults, also to no avail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20490/discussion-between-optichip-and-micah-rockstar-henning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of troubleshooting, I was able to determine that there was a Windows firewall rule enabled that would only allow connections from `PC1` over `TCP/135` and `TCP/1027` if the connection is secure.  In *Windows Firewall with Advanced Security* -> *Inbound Rules*, I went into the suspect rule properties.  On the General tab, under Action, *Allow the connection if it is secure* was selected.  On the Customize screen, *Allow the connection if it is authenticated and integrity-protected* was highlighted.  The description for that item is as follows:

```
Allow only connections that are both authenticated and integrity-protected 
by using IPsec.  Compatible with Windows Vista and later.
```

[image]

Somehow this rule was established through a group policy on the domain.  More than likely an administrator created this rule; however, it is possible that the software used on `PC1` that requires this communication could have created the rule if it was installed using a domain admin account.